# trouble with foreach loop $_FILES php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to insert multiple file names into `$NewFileNames`  array and then pass the complete array only once and with all filenames assigned to it, so I tried at first looping in this way using an increment variable

```
<?php
require "prepare.php";
    $allowUpload = true;
     $allowtypes    = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');
    $maxfilesize   = 80000000;
            if (isset($_FILES['uploadedFile'])) {
                $myFile = $_FILES['uploadedFile'];
                $fileCount = count($myFile["name"]);
                for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
                    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'][$i];
                if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
                    //Setup our new file path
                    $newFilePath = "uploads/" . $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][$i];
                    $NewFileNames = array();
                    array_push($NewFileNames,$newFilePath);
                    $imageFileType = pathinfo($newFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                if (file_exists($newFilePath))
                {
                require "other\\fileExsist.php";
                $allowUpload = false;
                }
                if ($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["size"][$i] > $maxfilesize)
                {
                require "other\\fileSize.php";
                $allowUpload = false;
                }

                if (!in_array($imageFileType,$allowtypes ))
                {
                    require "other\\fileExtenstion.php";
                    $allowUpload = false;
                }
                if ($allowUpload){
                    //Upload the file into the temp dir
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
                        //Handle other code here
                            if (!empty($NewFileNames)){
                                $Files = json_encode($NewFileNames);
                                echo '<script>start('.$Files.');</script>';
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

so, this code is not working in the right way because it inserts each file name to the array `$NewFileNames`  and then calls the js script function `start` in line 39 several times

```
if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
  if (!empty($NewFileNames)){
     $Files = json_encode($NewFileNames);
     echo '<script>start('.$Files.');</script>';
  }
}
```

but this is not what I'm trying to accomplish in this project I want the array to carry all the file names and call the javascript function `start($Files)` only once so, obviously the problem is with the first `for` loop so I thought using `foreach` will be easier and match what i want to do
so this is what i tried :

```
<?php
require "prepare.php";
    $allowUpload = true;
     $allowtypes    = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');
    $maxfilesize   = 80000000;
            if (isset($_FILES['uploadedFile'])) {
                $myFile = $_FILES['uploadedFile'];
                $fileCount = count($myFile["name"]);
                // for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
                foreach($_FILES['uploadedFile'] as $file) {
                    $tmpFilePath = $file['tmp_name'];
                if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
                    //Setup our new file path
                    $newFilePath = "uploads/" . $file['name'];
                    $NewFileNames = array();
                    array_push($NewFileNames,$newFilePath);
                    $imageFileType = pathinfo($newFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                if (file_exists($newFilePath))
                {
                require "other\\fileExsist.php";
                $allowUpload = false;
                }
                if ($file["size"] > $maxfilesize)
                {
                require "other\\fileSize.php";
                $allowUpload = false;
                }

                if (!in_array($imageFileType,$allowtypes ))
                {
                    require "other\\fileExtenstion.php";
                    $allowUpload = false;
                }
                if ($allowUpload){
                    //Upload the file into the temp dir
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
                        //Handle other code here
                            if (!empty($NewFileNames)){
                                $Files = json_encode($NewFileNames);
                                echo '<script>start('.$Files.');</script>';
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

and this code is given this error

```
Warning: Undefined array key "tmp_name"
```

Comment: And what's the question now? What **exactly** is not working with all that code? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase did you read the last two lines?

Comment: So, that warning is bothering you? Why not check what that array contains?

Comment: You're not checking the ["error"] key within the $_FILES entries at all. You *are* checking the ["size"] key, but only to cap it's maximum, not to see if it is **0**. Size=0 can happen when someone leaves an upload field empty (which i assume is the source of your issue).

Comment: Can I just suggest starting it simple. Strip all the obscure stuff that's at this point just cluttering the view. Do a simple `foreach($_FILES as $upload)` loop and get that working right. Then decorate with obscurities, one by one.